# Meta-analysis using p-values

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, meta-analysis

I have a study-level (quasi-experimental) estimator of treatment effect $\hat{\delta}_i$, where $i$ indexes the study. Due to the way the estimator is constructed, I do not have access to a measure of uncertainty, such as a standard error, but using a permutation test, I am able to construct a p-value ($\hat{p}_i$) of the hypothesis $\delta_i = 0$ at the study-level.

Now, I want to do meta-analysis & combine the study-level treatment effects using, say, the the DerSimonian-Laird random effects estimator into an estimator of the common treatment effect across studies.

$$
\bar{\hat{\delta}} = \sum_i w_i\hat{\delta}_i
$$
where $w_i = f(\hat{\mathbb{V}}(\hat{\delta}_i))$, that is the weights are some function of the uncertainty (typically the standard error) associated with the study-level treatment effect.

My questions is -- is there a way to use the p-value of the study to compute the weights instead?

Comment: You can do it the other way round, use the $\delta$ to weight the $p$.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, but that does not give me a value for $\bar{\hat{\delta}}$.

Comment: Yes, I know, it was just a possible alternative.

Comment: what do you mean by p-value (p^i) of the hypothesis δi=0 at the study-level ? Also please give formula or measure used for arriving at treatment effect ?